# How to play bottom pair in middle position?

Tags: nlhe, online, cash-game, no-limit

I was playing `NLHE` speed poker on microstakes. 
I had 6♥ 6⋄ in `MP` and I made a standard `3BB` bet. Then the button called.
The flop came J⋄7♠3♣. Made standard `50% pot` raise and the button called.

The turn came with Q♥ and now I was really confused what to do. Is my hand strong enough to bet? Or I should rather give up? Finally I checked and folded on buttom `1/3 pot` bet.

How should I play such hand?

Comment: What was your position, you  say you had 66 in MP, but your title says how to play on the botton. Is that supposed to be button or bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You played the hand just fine. Your *open-raise* was standard play.
You get a call from the *BTN* which may translate to either:

- a *loose* player having potential hands (eg. K8s, 75s, J9s, Q8o)
- a *tight* player with average or good holding that can't re-raise like `AT`
- a small to middle pair
- a *position-wise* call. He saw you raised from MP, so he lure you out after your *CBet* and he has position.

The *Flop* is dry, no flush or straight draws but not so without dangers. The `J` feeds in a number of marginal calling hands like `J7,J8,J9,JT,KJ` and there is a little army of calling hands that include `Ax,Kx,Qx,Jx` and other `small pairs`, although you have nothing to be afraid and a *Cbet* is required.

He called your *Cbet*. My play is to just check and not push it. Your play from the very start is to *set mine* and trying to win with a *CBet*, no? Although your opponent is still here, calling you. What that tells you? To me this translates to these cases:

- A `Jx`. A very feasible case, there are a number of `Jx` calling hands.
- A pair like `88,99` He thinks you'll shutdown after the *CBet* so he try to value bet you out.
- A slowplaying set.

In fact his `1/3` bet at the end seems like a bet that `wants you` to call. Bluffs are more expensive than a `1/3` so you have to believe him for either a `Q` or `J` or something better, without reads. Your fold was OK and a huge part of your *set mining* strategy, nothing to be worry about. But calling with `66` on a board with *3 cards higher* than your `66` and *2 of them on typical calling range* like `Q, J` would be a spewy play.

Comment: why did you say " Cbet is required"? please and thank you

Comment: The _CBet_ here is almost mandatory to me since the flop is a textbook one for _CBet_: 1 high card, 2 small cards. Additionally, no _straight_ or _flush_ draws. This kind of flop is 100% CBet in my book, since a calling range just don't hit that flop frequently. But there are other reasons to _CBet_ here. You many know you have `66` but to your opponent you may hold `AA,KK,QQ,AJ,QJ` kind of hands. A bet here forces an opponent holding `66,55,44,22,Ax,Kx,Qx` to fold the majority of the time. Furthermore, you want to win the pot **now** since you're afraid any card, mostly `A,K,Q,T` on turn.

Comment: Lastly, a _CBet_ here will give most of the time 2 free cards, on _turn_ and _river_ for a miracle `6` or cheap `showdown`. Since you're betting the flop, if Villain folds, you win. If he re-raises, you defined your hand and can get out _cheaply_.If he calls, then he'll afraid to bet on _turn_ fearing a check-raise, thus giving you 2 free cards most of the time. This kind of play of course is best done IP (in position). If you don't bet the flop and he bet the flop/turn, you're going to call, no? If yes, why not bet right now? If you're going to call Villain's bet, it's better to start betting

Answer (score 3):

If on the button and nobody has called, try to steal the blinds, if in early and middle position and nobody has raised limp. If in early  middle position and somebody raised fold.

If in  the blinds and somebody is raising very late or on the button, make a call. If somebody raises in early to middle position, this hand is a fold.

Raising this hand in early and middle position is simply a bad play, you are throwing your money away.

With small pocket pairs, you either want to be head up against somebody with out a pocket pair, or you want to be in a multi-way pot with four players or more. The more players you have, and the better your position the more willing you should be to call a raise.

Ok hand to defend a blind against a late raiser, ok hand to steal a blind with, were you have the benefit of being the aggressor and a good hand to hit a set with. In the hand with lots of players, you hit a set or a little flop with a straight draw or you let this hand go on the flop.

[A very good discussion of Pocket Pair play here at Poker SE.](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/384/set-mining-betting-pre-flop-with-22)